# Mixed Editions in a 3 Node SQL Server Always on Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I could not find any solid documentation anywhere, checking any of you have seen/built an AG that looks like below. Appreciate your responses.

**SQL SERVER 2016**

1. Primary - Enterprise edition
2. Secondary 1 - Enterprise edition - with Sync Replication
3. Secondary 2 - Standard Edition with Async Replication

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You might missed that the Availability Groups are only available in [Enterprise Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017#RDBMSHA).

In you scenario (with mixed edition), you would **neither** able to do following AG Configuration:

**[Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/overview-of-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)**
Required all replicas running Enterprise Edition

**[Basic Availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)** ([limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017#limitations))
It limit to two replicas only

**[Distributed Availability groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)**
Standard Edition only support Basic Availability Groups and Basic Availability Groups cannot be part of Distributed AGs